# Solving rate units from ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the units for the different methylation rates k+ and k- from this ODE.

[Ordinary differential equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcK6p.png)

I am unsure how to solve it, as I can't decide if I should treat R as a concentration (units M) or as a number (no units). I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is said that $R$ is a fraction (i.e. a percentage), thus it has no unit. Another way to see it is the factor $(1-R)$; 1 and $R$ should have the same units in order to be added, hence $[R] = 1$. Assuming that the methylation level $m$ is also a percentage (without units), one concludes $[k_\pm] = [\mathrm{Time}^{-1}]$.